# Searching different text fields for different words in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am trying to create an index to search for text in the **word** and **colour** field, and a search query but I can't seem to accomplish this.

**What I want to do**

I want to match a document based on certain conditions on the objects in the **individual** array. and, find a match if

(word = example, colour = green, number = 25)

**and there exist another object in the array with  the following criteria**

(word = "is", colour = blue, number = 9)

**What a document looks like**

```
theObject = {
    elements: "This is an example sentence, for demonstration only",
    individual: [
        {
            word: "example",
            colour: "green",
            number: 23
        },
        {
            word: "is",
            colour: "blue",
            number: 9;
        }, // etc the amount of objects depends on the number of words in the elements string.
    ],
    }
```

**Problem number 1, creating the index**

Since the number of elements in the **individual** array will depend on the number of words in the string **elements**. I don't know how to create an index

For example

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   {
     "individual[].colour": "text", // I know this is wrong.
     "individual[].word" : "text" // I know this is wrong.
   }
 )
```

How do I specify that I want to search every **colour** and **word** field?

**Problem number 2, the search query**

```
{$and: [
    {"$text": {"$search": "example green"}},
    { number: { $eq: 23 } }
]}
```

The first problem with this is that it searches the **word** field for both **example** and **green** instead of searching the **word** field for **example** and the **colour** field for **green**

The second problem is that i don't know how to combine the second criteria : that is

```
{$and: [
    {"$text": {"$search": "is blue"}},
    { number: { $eq: 9 } }
]}
```

Comment: Without index we can get only  match object, if you want i can share query

Comment: I think you are looking for this: [Index Arrays with Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/index.html#index-arrays-with-embedded-documents).

Comment: @prasad This looks promising but unfortunately the documentation says that "$expr does not support multikey indexes.". which is crucial moving forward with my project.